# Limitation in IISExpress on DB connections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, iis-express

Developing a simple MVC5 application that connects to SQL Server 2012 and gets some data. Home page of the application has a JavaScript that on

`setInterval('myFunction()', 10000);`

using AJAX call rebinds my model with the latest changes in the database. When application is being deployed to the server it runs as expected for days (no errors in the log), but during development, when application hosted in IISExpress I'm getting error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I was Googling the problem for several hours and all points to leaking SQL connection or DataReader that not being closed properly, but using simple select statement I see only one or two connections being open concurrently (and they are being timely released)

```
DECLARE  @sp_who2 TABLE(SPID INT,Status VARCHAR(255),
  [Login]  VARCHAR(255),HostName  VARCHAR(255), 
  BlkBy  VARCHAR(255),DBName  VARCHAR(255), 
  Command VARCHAR(255),CPUTime INT, 
  DiskIO INT,LastBatch VARCHAR(255), 
  ProgramName VARCHAR(255),SPID2 INT, 
  REQUESTID INT) 
INSERT INTO @sp_who2 EXEC sp_who2
SELECT      * 
FROM       @sp_who2
WHERE       ProgramName = 'myProgram'
ORDER BY    DBName ASC
```

I verified code several times and see that connections and readers being closed and disposed everywhere properly.
What else can be wrong? Or it is just some limitations in IIS Express???

**UPDATE**
 My connection string looks like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=MyDBServer;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Max Pool Size=100; Connection Timeout=30;Application Name=myApplication"
```

Comment: Can you post your connection string please ?

Comment: Which version of Windows is this running on? And which **edition** of Windows is this running on?

Comment: I'm assuming you're closing your connections when you're done with them?

Comment: Yes, all connections are closed properly - verified